I can't get nativewind to work on react native even after following the most basic of steps
Even after following guides tailwind still refuses to work on react native.
I have tried many things but this is the simplest approach I have found:
1. npx create-expo-app@latest App --template blank@latest
2. yarn add nativewind
3. yarn add --dev tailwindcss

tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./<custom directory>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

babel.config.js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: ["nativewind/babel"],
  };
};

App.js
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  return (
      <View className='flex-1 items-center justify-center'>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
    
  );
}

I would really appreciate some help since this is the only thing blocking me from making any type of app
